# can not load omniauth in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following [rails 3 in action](http://manning.com/katz/)'s source code,when I run the app,I get the following error:

```
[DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is deprecated and has no effect. Please remove it.

Could not load 'omniauth'. Please ensure you have the omniauth gem >= 1.0.0 installed and listed in your Gemfile.
Exiting
```

This is the gem file:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
# gem 'arel'
gem 'rack'
gem 'sprockets'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass', '~> 3.1.0.alpha'
gem 'coffee-script'

gem 'dynamic_form'

gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'

gem 'paperclip'

gem 'searcher'
gem 'kaminari'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "oa-oauth", :require => "omniauth/oauth"
gem "delayed_job"

# gem "forem"
gem "ticketee-forem"

gem 'sinatra'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'gmail'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6.1.beta1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

When I run `bundle check` it will success.

And my gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
addressable (2.2.8)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.2)
bundler (1.1.4)
cancan (1.6.8)
capybara (1.1.2)
childprocess (0.3.5)
cocaine (0.3.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
cucumber (1.0.6)
cucumber-rails (1.0.2)
database_cleaner (0.8.0)
delayed_job (3.0.3)
devise (2.1.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
dynamic_form (1.1.4)
email_spec (1.2.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.0.0)
faraday (0.6.1)
ffi (1.1.5)
gherkin (2.4.21)
gmail (0.4.0)
gmail_xoauth (0.3.2)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.2)
json (1.7.5)
kaminari (0.14.0)
launchy (2.1.0)
libwebsocket (0.1.5)
mail (2.4.4)
mime (0.1)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nokogiri (1.4.7)
oa-core (0.2.4)
oa-oauth (0.2.4)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.4.1)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paperclip (3.2.0)
pg (0.14.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rspec (2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.6.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
sass (3.1.21)
searcher (0.0.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.25.0)
sinatra (1.3.3)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
thor (0.16.0)
ticketee-forem (0.0.1)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
warden (1.2.1)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

As you can see, I do have the gem `oa-oauth (0.2.4)` installed.

Why does it give me this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oa-oauth is not the omniauth gem ... It's the oauth extension for omniauth ... Add the omniauth gem `gem 'omniauth'`, just like the error message tells you ...

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. It should be possible to include only the oa-oauth part. See https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Selectively-loading-omniauth-gems